# Asking for requirements suggestions in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, closed-questions

I'm starting to write an file-hosting website like Rapidshare. Can I ask requirements for the subject? It is programming related in the end and I don't want to hit an iceberg after I start coding. Yet I don't know if it would be closed.

edit: For people who think it would be advertising and stuff. It's not a site I plan to launch. It's a school project. I just want to know how I should define the scope.

The ones I have thought so far:
-Files should be in a non-shared folder
-They probably should have their own folders
-Server has to manage processes that transmit data to user

I'm new to web programming. I just want to have a basic guideline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say no, that's more of a marketing thing and too close advertising your own product/site.  Programming / code questions you have while writing the site, that's different.

**EDIT:**
Have a look at this question on SO for tips on what technical details to include when building a new site:

[**What should a developer know before building a public web site?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  It's not a question for programmers, it's a question for users.

Comment: But it's not a product. It's just a school project. I just wanna do it as best as I can. Since I'm new in web-programming, I may miss some major points.

Comment: @Narsil - that's great and I understand where you're coming from!  Requirements for a specific site, however, are very localized to that site, which is outside of the scope of SO.  "What do I need to include for this type of web site" is not going to fly.  "What do I need to do for my site to make it work in MVC", for example, will get you farther.

Comment: @Narsil: see my edit for a good list of technical details for new sites.

Comment: I am gonna check it
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think requirements analysis is fine fodder for a programming site, we'd have much better programs out there with more up-front thought.  Just make sure you're clearly asking for **Technical** Requirements, like "What method would I use in ASP.net to read a file in?" (made up).

StackOverflow is not the place for User Requirements.

Comment: Requirements analysis is very different from collecting requirements...

Comment: @Polly, hmmm, I see your points from your comments on both answers.  I was thinking of more technical requirements, but it does look like he means 'user requirements'.  I've edited my answer.